# GODADDY server configuration for file upload in php

Tags: php, shared-hosting

I have to configure on godaddy server that when I upload a file then it should store that file  to a particular folder

I am using wamp server locally and there I created an uploads folder to keep the uploaded files using the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST["btnImport"]))
                 {
                      $uploads_dir = 'C:/wamp/www/quiz admin/uploads';
                      $tmp_name = $_FILES["excelFile"]["tmp_name"];
                      $name = $_FILES["excelFile"]["name"];
                    if(!empty($_FILES["excelFile"]["tmp_name"]))
                     {
                        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
                        $fileupload = $_FILES["excelFile"]["tmp_name"];                          
                        $fileName = explode(".",$_FILES["excelFile"]["name"]);
                        if($fileName[1]=="xls"||$fileName[1]=="xlsx")
                        {
                   $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($uploads_dir.'/'.$name);
```

How to do this on the remote server, where to create folder and what should be the path for that folder or directory ??

Comment: If you wont' use a professional hosting environment then your SOL.  Sorry dude.

Answer (score 1):

Figure out the physical local where your files are hosted.

Use the [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__FILE__`

```
Example: echo dirname(__FILE__);
```

Change your code accordingly,

$uploads_dir = 'To physical location retrieved using `_FILE_`';